# SonataAdminBundle

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-sonata

How can i create custom page with only one button **Start Parsing** using **SonataAdminBundle**. Is  SonataAdminBundle suitable for this ? Or it good only for create/edit/delete CRUD interfaces ?

I want to have all admin functions in one admin panel, how can i add page with all-custom actions ?

Can i create page in SonataAdminBundle which doesn't extends Sonata\AdminBundle\Admin\Admin ?

```
class CustomAdmin
{

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just create admin class for any entity as usually. In service definition specify your controller and override listAction for example as a default action for menu link. In list action render your template or do any other stuff that you need